# Returning a users lat lng as a string iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-location

Is there a way to return the users location as a string from a model?

I have a model thats job is to download same JSON data from a web service.  When sending in my request I need to add ?lat=LAT_HERE&lng=LNG_HERE to the end of the string.

I have seen tons of examples using the map or constantly updating a label.  But I cant find out how to explicitly return the lat and lng values.

Im only 2 days into iPhone dev so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to leverage Core Location, specifically [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager). Apple doesn't provide any CL programming guide, so just look at one of the samples like [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801) to see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CLLocationManager like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
    {  
        // this creates the CCLocationManager that will find your current location
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    // this delegate is called when the app successfully finds your current location
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
    {
        // retrieve lat and lng in a string from newLocation.coordinate
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }

    // this delegate method is called if an error occurs in locating your current location
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
    {
     NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
    }
```